# Наследование методов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, наследование

Есть два класса: enemy и bullet, как нужно сделать наследование чтобы враг мог использовать метод пули?

```
class enemy:  
class bullet(enemy):
```

или

```
class bullet:
class enemy(bullet):
```

Comment: второй вариант. Но желательно описать подробнее задачу

Comment: Пуля и враг вообще должны быть двумя независимыми классами. Наследование - это, например, если класс собака унаследован от класса животного, то про конкретную собаку можно сказать, что она животное, и что она собака. А вы, получается, хотите чтобы враг был пулей?